# When to Call ViewModel.LoadData?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a WP7 Silverlight app that displays a bunch of data using Pivot. When first creating the project, the Visual Studio template calls ViewModel.LoadData in Page_Loaded:

```
private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    App.ViewModel.LoadData();
}
```

However [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.onnavigatedto%28VS.95%29.aspx) it says you should use OnNavigatedTo instead of Page_Loaded, because OnNavigatedTo is called only once when a page becomes active, while Page_Loaded is called everytime an item is added to the page's visual tree. The MSDN article is for Silverlight 4 instead of for Silverlight Windows Phone though.

> You override the OnNavigatedTo method
>   to examine the navigation request and
>   prepare the page for display. For
>   example, you can load the requested
>   data and enable or disable visual
>   elements.
>
> Typically, you use the OnNavigatedTo
>   method instead of creating an event
>   handler for the Loaded event. The
>   OnNavigatedTo method is preferable
>   because it is only called once for
>   each time the page becomes active. The
>   Silverlight framework raises the
>   Loaded event each time the element is
>   added to the visual tree, which
>   potentially can happen more than once
>   when activating a page.   The
>   OnNavigatedTo method is called for
>   each request, even when the page is
>   retrieved from the cache. You should
>   include in this method code that must
>   be executed for each request rather
>   than placing that code in the Page
>   constructor.

Is there any reason why the Visual Studio Pivot template calls ViewModel.LoadData in Page_Loaded?

Comment: "while Page_Loaded is called everytime an item is added to the page's visual tree." any reference?

Comment: I referenced the wrong link. The document on MSDN about OnNavigatedTo is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.onnavigatedto(VS.95).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're confusing LayoutUpdated and Loaded.
Loaded should only get called once each time the page is displayed.

Loading data specific to a page after that page has been constructed is a simple way of working with data tied to a specific page. My guess is that the default templates use this as it's simple to understand and learn from.

**Update**
The article in MSDN that you refer to is for Page.Loaded. WP7 does not use `Page` instead it uses [`PhoneApplicationpage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff403401%28v=VS.92%29.aspx).
Having worked with WP7 for over a year and created dozens of apps, I've never seen the Loaded event called multiple times in a WP7 app.

Comment: No I'm not. Please refer to my updated question for remarks on MSDN.

Comment: Me neither actually. Just wanna be cautious of potential performance drags. So is there any difference of putting codes in Page_Load and OnNavigatedTo?

Comment: @Jim `OnNaigatedTo` could be called multiple times once a page has been loaded as you navigate between pages if the first page isn't being unloaded.

Comment: But from my experiment when navigating to another page and back, both Page_Load and OnNavigatedTo got triggered (OnNavigatedTo first, then Page_Load).

Comment: @Jim Is you page being unloaded when you navigate? If it isn't then loaded won't be called again. If it is then only OnNavigatedTo will be called.